# htaccess both ending slash and no slash to extension(.html)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following content in `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\..+)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

What I'm trying to do is to redirect `site.com/category` and `site.com/category/` to `site.com/category.html`

The code that I have so far is doing redirecting `/category` to `/category.html` but not `/category/(Multiple choices shows up)`

I would like some explanation of the regex in this line as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\..+)$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make trailing slash optional:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /category/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```

This condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\..+)$
```

is matching request URI if doesn't contain a `/` or a DOT plus some text.

However as you can see this is not even needed as per my suggested answer.

Comment: Now it redirects to `/category/.html`

Comment: Yes, it works BUT it doesn't rewrite the last chunk. I mean if I have `/category/subcategory/` it becames `/subcategory.html`. It cuts out `/category/`. Maybe I have to add the REQUEST_URI somewhere? Sorry for not mentioning that earlier in the question.

Comment: Is this .htaccess in `/category/` sub-directory and not in site root?

Comment: Umm, yes. Guess that's the reason, right? All files are in a subfolder where I'm testing it.

Comment: In that case use `RewriteBase /category/` (change to your real sub-dir name)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!